# Multi tenant app following example (MVC + Ninject)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, multi-tenant

I'm following this example to develop a multi tenant app: [Simple approach to multi-tenancy in ASP.NET MVC Part 2](http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Simple-approach-to-multi-tenancy-in-ASPNET-MVC-Part-2.aspx)

Instead using StructureMap I'm using Ninject. In the example is used this inteface:

**IContainerResolver** – gets the IoC container for the resolved tenant

But I can't understand how to use it with Ninject. Is some sort NinjectModule so each tenant has his proper bindings?

Can you explain to me **Why is used and How I must use it with Ninject**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I wouldn't do such a thing in the given scenario because you can leave that up to IIS. Just deploy your app for your tenants with a different App.config have a really reliable separation of the memory.

But if you really want to go that way there is a very simple solution by loading tenant modules into one shared kernel:

```
public class TenantSpecificBindingsModule 
{
    TenantSpecificBindingsModule(string tenantUrl)
    {
    }

    public void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<ISomeTenantSpecifiComponent>.To<Impl>().When(GetCurrentUrl().StartsWith(tenantUrl));
    }
}

foreach tenant { kernel.Load(new TenantSpecificBindingsModule(tenant.Url));
```

Comment: Additional information: The app will be hosted in Azure, so I will have only one app. The tenant's information (like Connection String) will be stored in SQL Azure. I was thinking in first identify the tenant (based on URL) and then instanciate the bindings. My question was oriented to the meaning of IContainerResolver in the example, because I didn't know how to use that interface...

Comment: @kikein I just telling you that this isn't the way you'd do such a thing with Ninject because it is much simpler by registering modules that add tennant specific bindings. Not everything can be translated one to one.